# Rewrite rule for 301 redirect in web.config

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config

I have traffic hitting my site to the following urls:

```
mydomain.com/post-title/amp/
```

I want all traffic going to urls ending in `/amp/` to remove the `/amp/` and redirect to the normal blog post which would look like this:

```
mydomain.com/post-title/
```

How do I write a url redirect rule in web.config that would perform a 301 redirect?